# How to use a look up in a hashtable vb.net

Tags: vb.net

**EDIT**
I have created a Hash table and I want to do a lookup and extract the Name value where ID is = line.substring(4,2).

**ID    Name**

01     John

02     Bob

03     Joe

04     Mary

I have the following code:

```
    Sub Main()
    ' Create Hashtable instance.
    Dim table As Hashtable = New Hashtable

    table.Add("01", "John")
    table.Add("02", "Bob")
    table.Add("03", "Joe")
    table.Add("04", "Mary")

    '-lookup and extract the Name value where ID is = line.substring(4,2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I have edited my question and added some sample code :)

Comment: The id is **NOT** 01, 02, etc?

Comment: @Martha where is `line` coming from? If you just want to search for a key, I believe you can simply do this : `table.item("03")` where it looks for the key `03` and returns the value.

Comment: The Hashtable class became obsolete at the same time the ArrayList class did. Since generics were introduced in 2005, we use the generic List and Dictionary classes.

Comment: If you are using a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`, you can look up a value by accessing it directly e.g. `Dim value = myDictionary(key)` which will throw if the key isn't present, or you can use `TryGetValue` to test and retrieve (saving an extra key lookup).  If you just want to check if the value is there, you can use `ContainsKey`.  If you're using a .NET Core version (including .NET 5+), you can use `TryAddValue` to do a conditional add, but note that this routine isn't in .NET Framework.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you I will keep in mind to use the generic List and Dictionary classes in the future. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed, use a Generic `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.

...but, here's how to do what you asked:

```
Dim table As Hashtable = New Hashtable

table.Add("01", "John")
table.Add("02", "Bob")
table.Add("03", "Joe")
table.Add("04", "Mary")

Dim line As String = "abcd02efg"
Dim ID As String = line.Substring(4, 2)
If table.ContainsKey(ID) Then
    Dim value As String = table(ID)
    MessageBox.Show(ID & " = " & value)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Key not found! ID = " & ID)
End If
```